# how to get input of time in solidity?

Tags: solidity, timers, datetime, timelock

I want to run a session for a product in auction , my product struct contains the time interval we need for being the session of the bidding.

While initializing a product, I need to take the input of how much time interval they want their product to be in active bidding.

How can I take the inputs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All times in the blockchain are stored in *Unix epoch* format ([How to calculate with time and dates?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37026/how-to-calculate-with-time-and-dates/37027)). The timestamp of execution can be retrieved with keyword `now`.

So basically you just need to convert your start/end dates into Unix epoch timestamps and then compare them to `now`.

You can also consider measuring elapsed time with block numbers (some developers prefer that method in the long run, for example https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28472/31933) as the time interval between blocks is quite well known (although a bit inaccurately). But also some developers claim that timestamps are more accurate than block intervals (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/24351/31933). You can decide for yourself.